# UDP port forwarding with iptables in OpenVPN server

Tags: iptables, openvpn, udp, vps

How to forwards all the UDP ports? I setup an OpenVPN server on my debian VPS & by using iptables, I forwarded all the TCP ports except 1100 & 1200. Here is the command that I used:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport ! --dports 1100,1200 -d <vps-server-ip> -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2`

(10.8.0.2 is the client IP of OpenVPN)

TCP port forwarding works correctly. I can confirm this from this site: https://portscanner.standingtech.com/

However, I applied the same command for UDP ports but it doesn't work like TCP. UDP ports doesn't forward:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p udp -m udp -m multiport ! --dports 1100,1200 -d <vps-server-ip> -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2`

Basically I want to open all the TCP & UDP ports in my server except some of them.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The rules order is important. Maybe you have some other command before "-t nat" for UDP which drop traffic on udp.

Comment: @mariaczi, I am using those commands:

 `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport ! --dports 1100,1200 -d <vps-server-ip> -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2`

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p udp -m udp -m multiport ! --dports 1100,1200 -d <vps-server-ip> -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2`

`iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -d 10.8.0.2 -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp -d 10.8.0.2 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: As root run `iptables -L -n | grep Chain` and show output.

Comment: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

Comment: This server is directly connect to the internet (have public IP) or you have other device with firewall before them?

Comment: The server has public IP. I directly connected with server via OpenVPN.

Comment: Rules are OK and should work. Check if the service(s) to which you try connect listen too on 10.8.0.2 (are not binded to public IP only).